# How can I split a one string list and can check what strings does it contain?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a chatbot an maximum code is done but I can't check the input correctly to make the chatbot respond to it.

I tried this `if "hi" in query:`, but it check every letter of it,
Like it sometime respond Hello sir even when I say "Friday who are you ?."

```
def recognize():
    try:
        import speech_recognition as sr
        r=sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=1)
            audio= r.listen(source,5,5)
            query = r.recognize_google(audio , language="en-IN") 
            return query
    except:
        pass

query = recognize().lower()
if "hi" in query:
   print("Hello Sir")
```

Is there any other way to fix it.

Comment: `if "hi" in query` won't count letters, it will only check if the string `'hi'` is present in the iterable `query`. Please provide clear examples of `query` and of your expected behavior

Comment: `"hi" in "hello sir"` is `False`. Do you want it to be true because each symbol of `hi` is contained in `hello sir`? What about `"hiii" in "hello sir"` - what is the desired result here (for duplicated `i`s)?

Comment: Given the fact that your input comes from speech recognition, you probably should `print(query)` to make sure that you have something you expect…

Comment: _but it check every letter of it_ No it does not.  `"hi"` is not in `"Friday who are you ?."`.  If you're getting true for that, then the actual string was not what you think it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if every character of one string is in another:

```
one = 'hi'
other = 'hello sir'

result = all(ch in other for ch in one)  # `True`, as both 'h' and 'i' are in `other`
```

However, if you want to check if one string is contained in another as a whole:

```
result = one in other  # `False`, as 'hi' is not in `other`
result = 'hell' in other  # `True`, as 'hell' is part of `other`
```